# How can the active area of a photodiode increased?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses, solar-cells, sensor

I use photo-diode [VTB8440BH](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/57158.pdf).
To increase its active area I was thinking to put a lens in front the diode would enlarge its active area.
What kind of lens would be beneficial one?
I was thinking of a setup as depicted in the picture. 
Do I think too naively or incorrectly?
[image]

Comment: A lens doesn't increase the active area of a photodiode, it merely converts a wide near-parallel beam into a convergent beam with a minimal focal radius. What that radius is and if it is equal or smaller than the size of your diode depends on the initial divergence of the beam and the focal length of the lens. Do you actually have a near-parallel beam?

Comment: well, the beam is not 100% parallel; however as long as the lens is able to catch the beam it should be able to focus it, isn't it?

Comment: As a correct design procedure you have to calculate the spot size from the beam divergence and make sure that it is the size of your diode. If it is too large, then you are losing light, if it is too small, then your diode picks up unnecessary electric noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the inverse of a high power single LED torch with a glass lens. If you look into one of the variable focus ones, with the LED off, you will clearly see the LED die taking up almost all of the field of vision through the lens. Just copy that setup.

This is an example of such a torch: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The setup of the torchlight can be transferred to my issue as following: 
1. I need to increase the gap btw. light beam and the glass lens
2. The gap between light beam and lens must be covered by a material like alumunium
case
Am I right?

Comment: You can use any opaque material to house the lens and diode. You could even buy a cheap torch and hack it to hold your diode instead of the LED.

Comment: I did try this. The current issue is that the lens concentrates the light a lot so that the concentrated light did miss to 'touch' the photodiode, instead it falls next to it.....the issue I see is that the light gets too focused...changing the distance btw lens and light beam does not really affect significantly the result. At this moment even without the lens the light amount on the photodiode is better..is there any suggestions u can make?

Comment: You need to adjust the diode so that it is at the focal point of the lens. If it is off to one side, you are obviously going to get a poor result.

Comment: Thx one final question.
I have a following assumption. Can you tell whether it is correct?

1. Now with the lens concentrated light falls on the photodiode.
2. Without the lens all light still falls on the photodiode, however light is spread.
--> The amount of current provided by the photodiode due to the light provided will be
the same with and without the lens.
Is this correct?

Comment: If the same amount of light falls on the active area of the diode then it will generate the same amount of current. The only difference might occur if the angle of incidence of the light was low, resulting in it being reflected from the glass of the diode. You can determine what this angle is by holding the diode and tilting it until you see the surrounding room clearly reflected in the glass.